# Font identification from an image

Tags: font-identification

I have a client that only has hard copies (business card and letterhead) of their logo. It's pretty simple, but I would like try to match the font as closely as I can.

Here is an image of their business card logo.

[image]

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: You can also use https://www.myfonts.com/WhatTheFont/ They also have an iOS app.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[whatfontis.com](http://www.whatfontis.com/) seems like a good online tool to identify fonts.

The closest match I could find was "Niagara Solid".

A simple preview below:

[image]

Comment: Good match! The example is obviously 'squooshed' vertically.

Comment: whatfontisit isn't very good, it can't tell what are letters, it fails on the Google logo horribly, etc

Comment: Thank you...I did try whatfontisit and it never gave me both the G and the L correct in the same font. This looks great!